# Prove that either the average of the numbers $a_{1}, a_{2},..., a_{n}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a_{1}, a_{2},..., a_{2n}$ be positive real numbers such that $a_{j}a_{n+j}=1$ for the values $j=1,2,...,n$
>
> **($a$)**  Prove that either the average of the numbers $a_{1}, a_{2},..., a_{n}$ is at least 1 or the average of the numbers $a_{n+1}, a_{n+2},..., a_{2n}$ is at least $1$
>
> **($b$)**  Assuming that $n\geq 2$ prove that there exist two distinct numbers $j,k$ in the set $\left \{ 1,2,..,2n \right \}$ such that $$\left | a_{j}-a_{k} \right |< \frac{1}{n-1}$$

I tried to write part $(a)$ like this $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{n}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{n+i}}{n}$$
but I don't know if it's true,

the part $(b)$m I think there will be exactly $n$ values of $i$ for which $0< a_{i}\leq 1$

and by the way, this is Olympiad question, any help will thankful.

Comment: Should that be $a_ja_{n+j}=1$?

Comment: that's correct, thanks

Comment: Your work has no context, I have no idea what you mean to accomplish by writing what you did. An expression has no means of being "correct". Have you tried a few cases? For $n=1$ it is almost trivially true that $a_1a_2=1 \iff a_1\ge1$ or $a_2\ge 1$. Care to try $n=3$ or $n=4$ and maybe generalize/induct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I will complete with your solution,

Part **$(a)$** $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{n}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{n+i}}{n}$$
$$\Rightarrow  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i-1}^{n}\left ( a_{i}+\frac{1}{a_{i}} \right )\geq 2$$

Therefore either $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{n}\geq 1$$ or $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{n+i}}{n}\geq 1$$

**DONE**

**(b)** there will be exactly $n$ values of $i$ for which $0< a_{i}\leq 1$. Partition $(0,1]$ into $n-1$ intervals $(\frac{a}{n-1}, \frac{a+1}{n-1}]$ 
for $a=0,1,...,n-2$.

Therefore, by the Dirichlet principle, there are distinct $j,k$ such that $a_{j}, a_{k}$ are in the same half-open interval of length $1/(n-1)$ and $$\left | a_{j}-a_{k} \right |< \frac{1}{n-1}$$

**AND WE'RE DONE**

Comment: How does an expression imply an inequality?

Comment: @DavidP It does.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

a) It's enough to show that the average of all the numbers is at least $1$. You can do this with a famous inequality...

b) At least $n$ of the numbers must lie in $(0,1]$. Use the pigeonhole principle, with intervals of length $\frac{1}{n-1}$ as your pigeonholes.